# Why is syntax highlighting missing from my recent answers unless I specify the language?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

For a few days (weeks?), I don't have syntax highlighting any longer for C# code I'm writing, unless I add:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
```

before the piece of code.

[Here's the example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/251617/6605) of code which will appear plain black if `<!-- language: c# -->` is missing.

Is this affecting only me? Is it expected?

Comment: Sometimes there's a lag, but that seems very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [language highlighting rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) are determined by the tags applied to the question. In this case, the question doesn't have any language tags, so it looks like you need to be explicit. You'd also have to be explicit in the event that your code was in a language that was not part of the question's tags.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Indeed, I suppose that none of the recent questions I answered where I encountered the issue were tagged C#.